# Angularjs wait until

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have:

```
$scope.bounds = {}
```

And later in my code:

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.load', function(){
    console.log('runs');
    Dajaxice.async.hello($scope.populate, {
                'west' : $scope.bounds.southWest.lng,
                'east': $scope.bounds.northEast.lng,
                'north' : $scope.bounds.northEast.lat,
                'south': $scope.bounds.southWest.lat,
    });
});
```

The bounds as you can see at the begging they are empty but they are loaded later (some milliseconds) with a javascript library ([leaflet angular](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/)). However the `$scope.$on(...)` runs before the bounds have been set so the `'west' : $scope.bounds.southWest.lng,` returns an error with an undefined variable.

What I want to do is to wait the bounds (`southWest` and `northEast`) to have been set and then run the `Dajaxice.async.hello(...)`.

So I need something like "wait until bounds are set".

Comment: Not sure if this is just a typo or not, but your `$scope.bound = {};` is missing an 's' so `$scope.bounds.` doesn't exist and therefore is undefined.  Alternatively, you should use `$scope.$watch('bounds',function(newVal,oldVal){ .. stuff here ..})` to see if the variable has changed and loaded what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$watch` for this purpose, something like this:

```
 $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.load', function(){

       $scope.$watch( "bounds" , function(n,o){  

           if(n==o) return;

           Dajaxice.async.hello($scope.populate, {
               'west' : $scope.bounds.southWest.lng,
               'east': $scope.bounds.northEast.lng,
               'north' : $scope.bounds.northEast.lat,
               'south': $scope.bounds.southWest.lat,                
            });

       },true);
 });
```

Comment: No clue how, but i works. I know what the basic `$watch` does but what does the `if(n==o) return;` and the `true` do at the end?

Comment: @Diolor `function(n,o)` gets old and new value of `bounds` , and if they are equal it does nothing and simply returns. `true` means: *Compare object for equality rather than for reference.*

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this every time the bounds change, you should just use a $watch expression:

```
$scope.$watch('bounds',function(newBounds) {
   ...          
});
```

If you only want to do it the first time the bounds are set, you should stop watching after you've done your thing:

```
var stopWatching = $scope.$watch('bounds',function(newBounds) {
  if(newBounds.southWest) {
     ...
     stopWatching();
  }
});
```

You can see it in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/nTKx1uwsAEalc7Zgss2r?p=preview